# What's new in Linux 3.0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Linus Torvalds just announced that he's releasing version 3.0-rc7. So what's new in Linux 3.0 when it comes to:

- Architecture
- Stability
- Security
- Hardware support
- etc

Answer (score 3):

From Linus Torvalds himself:

**"So what are the big changes?"**

> NOTHING. Absolutely nothing. Sure, we have the usual two thirds driver
>   changes, and a lot of random fixes, but the point is that 3.0 is just
>   about renumbering, we are very much not doing a KDE-4 or a Gnome-3
>   here. No breakage, no special scary new features, nothing at all like
>   that. We've been doing time-based releases for many years now, this is
>   in no way about features. If you want an excuse for the renumbering,
>   you really should look at the time-based one ('20 years') instead.

([Source](http://infoturtle.ie/juice/index.php?q=node/140))